# Control file for Excel macro

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file

I have a Excel-macro that I also use for running a command-line program. In that macro I have set up some parameters for different filepaths, filenames and so on, which I now want to put in (maybe) a Windows batch-file so that I (or users) don't need to touch the macro but can make changes to the filepaths in that .bat control file and get the macro to change its values accordingly.

How could I achieve such a task? Maybe there are examples out there you can point me towards.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Excel does not provide any standard documented way to pass parameters to a workbook from the commandline.

However, there is an undocumented, tricky and somewhat limited way to do it. Abusing the Excel's `/e` parameter.

in your BAT file you invoke excel this way

```
 start excel "workbook.xls" /e/oneparm/anotherparm/yetanotherparm
```

and then in workbook.xls file, you access the commandline with the function

```
 Declare Function GetCommandLineA Lib "Kernel32" () As String
```

and then just parse it ...

```
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   ...
   commandline = GetCommandLineA
   ...
   epos = Search("/e", commandline, 1) + 1
   p1pos = Search("/", commandline, epos) + 1 
   onearg = Mid(commandline, epos, p1pos-epos)

   p2pos = Search("/", commandline, p1pos)
   anotherarg = Mid(commandline, p1pos, p2pos-p1pos)
   ...
```

caveat, this method is very limited, it does not work if there are blanks or slashes or ampersands or carets or other reserved chars in the parameters. To overcome this limitation you'll need to implement some encoding method in the parameters; for such cases, I usually use *urlencoding* but any other trick (substituting blanks with underscores or with plus signs.decision is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way from a batch file is to simply set some environmental variables; they will be inherited by excel when its process is created;

**Bat**

```
set FILE_1=c:\bleep\bloop\some.file
set HELLO=Hello bob
set TAX=17.5
start excel "c:\null\book1.xlsm"
```

**Excel**

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
msgbox environ$("FILE_1")
msgbox environ$("HELLO")
msgbox environ$("TAX")
```